# Average Insertion Rate

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've got a table with a column indicating the date and time each row was inserted into the table. I'm trying to get a statistics for the average and peak rates of insertions:

- Peak insertions per minute
- Peak insertions per second
- Average insertions per minute
- Average insertions per second

I can envisage a solution using a `GROUP BY` to put the data into "buckets" (one for each interval) and then average the count of items in each, however it seems a very clunky solution.

Is there a more elegant T-SQL solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Grouping Sets** are the way to go, they're are intended for this very application of grouping by multiple sets of grouping attributes (grouping sets) in one query, and should result in better execution plans i.e. better performance:

```
-- if you weren't grouping by minutes and seconds this would
-- probably look more 'elegant'
SELECT      
    GROUPING_ID(
        YEAR(orderdate), 
        MONTH(orderdate), 
        DAY(orderdate), 
        DATEPART(hour, orderdate),
        DATEPART(MINUTE, orderdate),
        DATEPART(SECOND, orderdate)) AS grp_id,
    MAX([Insertions])                AS max_insertions,
    AVG([Average])                   AS avg_insertions,
    YEAR(orderdate)                  AS order_year,
    MONTH(orderdate)                 AS order_month, 
    DAY(orderdate)                   AS order_day, 
    DATEPART(HOUR, orderdate)        AS order_hour,
    DATEPART(MINUTE, orderdate)      AS order_minute,
    DATEPART(SECOND, orderdate)      AS order_second -- this will be null if the grouping set is minute
FROM Sales.Orders
GROUP BY
   GROUPING SETS
   (
       (
            -- grouping set 1: order second
            YEAR(orderdate), 
            MONTH(orderdate), 
            DAY(orderdate), 
            DATEPART(hour, orderdate),
            DATEPART(MINUTE, orderdate),
            DATEPART(SECOND, orderdate)
        ),
        (
            -- grouping set 2: order minute
            YEAR(orderdate), 
            MONTH(orderdate), 
            DAY(orderdate), 
            DATEPART(hour, orderdate),
            DATEPART(MINUTE, orderdate)
        )
    );
```

Comment: A nice little intro to this feature here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29312/Grouping-Sets-in-T-SQL-SQL-Server-2008

Comment: Looks like it's exactly what I want. Worth mentioning that `GROUPING_ID` was introduced in SQL Server 2008, for those stuck on earlier versions.

Comment: @Programming Hero - I'm not 100% sure, but I believe there is an alternative to GROUPING_ID...

Comment: @Programming Hero - you can use GROUPING() to indicate the current grouping set of the result record in pre-2008

Comment: I guess you could alternatively do grouping like this: `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(), '20010101')), (DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(), '20010101')) )`. Accordingly, some columns in the SELECT clause would be different too.

Answer (score 2):

**`GROUP BY` is the way to go.**

I would just make a `CTE` for each time interval you want, and select the max for each one:

```
;WITH CTEMinute AS
(
    SELECT  YEAR(datefield) yr, 
            MONTH(datefield) mo, 
            DAY(datefield) d, 
            DATEPART(hour, datefield) hr, 
            DATEPART(minute, datefield) Mint, 
            COUNT(*) as 'Inserts'
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY    YEAR(datefield), 
                MONTH(datefield), 
                DAY(datefield), 
                DATEPART(hour, datefield), 
                DATEPART(minute, datefield)
)
,CTESecond AS
(
    SELECT YEAR(datefield) yr, 
            MONTH(datefield) mo, 
            DAY(datefield) d, 
            DATEPART(hour, datefield) hr, 
            DATEPART(minute, datefield) Mint, 
            DATEPART(second, datefield) sec, 
            COUNT(*) as 'Inserts'
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY    YEAR(datefield), 
                MONTH(datefield), 
                DAY(datefield), 
                DATEPART(hour, datefield), 
                DATEPART(minute, datefield), 
                DATEPART(second, datefield)

)
```

Then you can just select from those `CTE`s to get max/min/avg values per time unit.

If you want it to be more elegant you can potentially just make on `CTE` for as fine granularity as you are likely to want (i.e. milliseconds or whatever), and then you can `SELECT`/`GROUP BY` that.

The issue with doing that is `CTE`s don't really perform that well since they are basically disposable views with no indexes or anything, so aggregating a CTE within another query will quickly bog down.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on J Coopers answer, I think the Rollup Feature might be what you're after.

```
SELECT      
    MAX([Insertions])                AS max_insertions,
    AVG([Average])                   AS avg_insertions,
     YEAR(orderdate),    AS YEAR
    MONTH(orderdate),   AS MONTH
    DAY(orderdate), AS DAY
    DATEPART(hour, orderdate), AS HOUR
    DATEPART(MINUTE, orderdate), AS MINUTE
    DATEPART(SECOND, orderdate) AS SECOND

FROM Sales.Orders
GROUP BY ROLLUP(
        YEAR(orderdate), 
        MONTH(orderdate), 
        DAY(orderdate), 
        DATEPART(hour, orderdate),
        DATEPART(MINUTE, orderdate),
        DATEPART(SECOND, orderdate)
    )
```

Comment: I've not leveraged `ROLLUP` before. Can you expand on it?

Comment: If using rollup, you are going to get additional levels of grouping that you may not be interested in - Min and Sec + Year, Month, Day, Hour. Of course you can filter these out. @Programming Hero - check out the link Spence posted in comment under my post

Comment: I think if you enclose all ROLLUP items but last into another pair of brackets, no extra level of grouping should be produced. I mean like this: `ROLLUP( (YEAR(orderdate), ..., DATEPART(MINUTE, orderdate)), DATEPART(SECOND, orderdate) )`.